# Define Block Blob size in GB

Tags: azure, storage

I have used the following code to define the block blob size in MB and then download this file. Its working fine.

```
protected void btn_download_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btndownloadrow = (Button)sender;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)btndownloadrow.NamingContainer;

        Label lblfilename = (Label)row.FindControl("lblGrid_filename");
        string downloadfile = lblfilename.Text.ToString();
        AccountFileTransfer = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=" + ACCOUNTNAME + ";AccountKey=" + ACCOUNTKEY);
        if (AccountFileTransfer != null)
        {
            BlobClientFileTransfer = AccountFileTransfer.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            ContainerFileTransfer = BlobClientFileTransfer.GetContainerReference(CONTAINER);
            ContainerFileTransfer.CreateIfNotExist();
        }
        var blob = ContainerFileTransfer.GetBlockBlobReference(downloadfile);
        var sasUrl = blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = new CloudBlockBlob(sasUrl);
       var blobSize = 551* 1024 * 1024; // Block blob size of 551 MB
       int blockSize = 1024 * 1024 * 1; //  chunk of size 1 MB

        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM";
        System.String disHeader = "Attachment; Filename=\"" + blockBlob.Name + "\"";
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", disHeader);
        for (long offset = 0; offset < blobSize; offset += blockSize)
        {
            using (var blobStream = blockBlob.OpenRead())
            {
                if ((offset + blockSize) > blobSize)
                    blockSize = (int)(blobSize - offset);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[blockSize];
                blobStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
                Response.Flush();
            }
        }
        Response.End();
    }
```

The problem which I am facing is that when I tried to define the block blob size in GB I am getting overflow error. I am trying to download a file of size around 3 gb. I am using this:-
      var blobSize = 3558 * 1024 * 1024; // trying to define the block blob size of around 3 GB here I am getting overflow error
    Could you please help me so that I can define the block blob size in GBs so that I can download the file from azure using block blob storage.

Answer (score 0):

I found the Answer of above error(overflow error).

What I did to get rid of above error is that I just appended "L" for Long type and the error vanished.

var blobSize = 3558L * 1024 * 1024;

Hope It helps someone.

Thanks.